# SQL populate with autoincrement, but reset on foreign key changed

Tags: sql

[image: Image 1]

Hi, I have table like this and I have to populate column Test with autoincrement, but autoincrement must reset to 1 each time DAId foreign key is changes.

I need sql script to execute in .net core migration.

This should be final resault.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `row_number()`:

```
select id, daid,
       row_number() over (partition by daid order by id) as test
from t;
```

If you want to update the value, then the syntax depends on the database.  The mention of ".net" suggests SQL Server.  If so, that has a very convenient ability called updatable CTEs:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
           row_number() over (partition by daid order by id) as new_test
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set test = new_test;
```